# Proxies object instead of Entity in Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using Doctrine and Symfony and I faced with one problem. Instead of `AppBundle\Entity\Item` I got `Proxies__CG__\AppBundle\Entity\Item. with all data = null.

```
$test = $em->getRepository(Entity\Item::class)->find(159);
var_dump($test); exit;
```

What should I change?

```
object(Proxies\__CG__\AppBundle\Entity\Item)[5348]
  public '__initializer__' => 
    object(Closure)[5237]
  public '__cloner__' => 
    object(Closure)[5802]
  public '__isInitialized__' => boolean false
  private 'id' (AppBundle\Entity\Item) => int 159
  private 'name' (AppBundle\Entity\Item) => null
  private 'slug' (AppBundle\Entity\Item) => null
  private 'description' (AppBundle\Entity\Item) => null
  private 'price' (AppBundle\Entity\Item) => null
  private 'isFixedPrice' (AppBundle\Entity\Item) => null
  private 'isExchangable' (AppBundle\Entity\Item) => null
  private 'isDeliverable' (AppBundle\Entity\Item) => null
  private 'totalViewsCount' (AppBundle\Entity\Item) => null
  private 'condition' (AppBundle\Entity\Item) => null
  private 'soldAt' (AppBundle\Entity\Item) => null
  private 'category' (AppBundle\Entity\Item) => null
  private 'user' (AppBundle\Entity\Item) => null
  private 'attributes' (AppBundle\Entity\Item) => null
  private 'pics' (AppBundle\Entity\Item) => null
  protected 'createdAt' => null
  protected 'updatedAt' => null
  protected 'deletedAt' => null
```

I have to get $test->getItem()->getSlug(). In the database Item with this id exists.

Comment: symfony does lazy loading, meaning, as soon as you're actually using properties that would belong to `Entity\Item`, the Proxy object will return the actual object's properties.

Comment: @Jakumi is right about the lazy loading but you are basically testing $item->getItem()... or was that a typo?

Comment: @Cerad Sorry. Typo. I want to get $test->getSlug(). In the database, I have value "test". `var_dump($test->getSlug()); exit;`

` "error_message": "Entity of type 'AppBundle\\Entity\\Item' for IDs id(159) was not found"`

Comment: @Jakumi I know but it doesn't work. See my comment above.

Comment: in that case, check that you're connected to the correct database and if so, post your definition

Comment: @Jakumi Ofc I'm sure that I'm connected to the correct database. [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/meoH2Fp.png)

When I try to get any of old rows I get the error. But I just create a new row and the error doesn't exist.

Comment: @Jakumi Maybe it some cache after changing db (I got db yesterday from dump). How can I turn the lazy load off?

Comment: the proxying is actually something you would want. I would rather propose you clear the caches first, if that doesn't help, there might be another problem ... also post your entity definition

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The previous dev  used @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt", timeAware=true)
so some rows have deleted_at value in the database. That's a way they didn't return any data.